# Flutter - How do I scroll down a Card

Tags: flutter

My app currently looks like this:
[image]

And the here's the code behind it:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/painting.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.lightBlue),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
            child: Center(
                child: Column(children: [
      Card(
        shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                bottomLeft: Radius.circular(24),
                bottomRight: Radius.circular(24))),
        elevation: 30,
        child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 120, right: 15, bottom: 20, left: 15),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                TextField(
                  controller: TextEditingController(text: '12121+1212'),
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.none,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.end,
                  style: TextStyle().copyWith(fontSize: 70),
                  decoration: InputDecoration(border: InputBorder.none),
                ),
                Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                  child: Text(
                    'Result',
                    style: TextStyle().copyWith(fontSize: 36),
                  ),
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 6,
                  width: 25,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Colors.black,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(14))),
                )
              ],
            )),
      ),
      Expanded(child: Container())
    ]))));
  }
}
```

Now, I want to scroll down the this card to reveal a list above it,something like this:
https://youtu.be/qZtGjd_-KwI

I think it could be done with CustomScrollView, but as a novices CustomScrollView and Slivers are a bit complex for me to understand. A little help regrading how to go about this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `CustomScrollView`. This will get you close (but won't collapse the main body as in your video example). Note if you provide a `hasScrollBody` to true then you're body will shrink in response but it'll then overflow. Even a ConstrainedBox with minimum height didn't work for me so that shrinking part is really the hardest part.

```dart
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  final centerKey = GlobalKey();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        center: centerKey,
        slivers: [
          const SliverAppBar(title: Text('The real title')),
          SliverList(
            delegate: SliverChildListDelegate.fixed(
              [
                Container(
                  color: Colors.pink,
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                    children: [
                      Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 200.0,
                        color: Colors.pink,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 200.0,
                        color: Colors.blue,
                      ),
                      Container(
                        width: double.infinity,
                        height: 200.0,
                        color: Colors.red,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          SliverAppBar(
            key: centerKey,
            expandedHeight: 100.0,
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            flexibleSpace: const Card(
              margin: EdgeInsets.zero,
              elevation: 14.0,
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
                  bottom: Radius.circular(32.0),
                ),
              ),
              child: SizedBox.expand(),
            ),
          ),
          SliverFillRemaining(
            hasScrollBody: false,
            child: SafeArea(
              top: false,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 16.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  children: List.generate(5, (i) => i).map((i) {
                    return Expanded(
                      child: Row(
                        children: List.generate(4, (i) => i).map((i) {
                          return const Expanded(
                            child: Placeholder(),
                          );
                        }).toList(),
                      ),
                    );
                  }).toList(),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The main part you should concern yourself with is the `centerKey`. That tells the CustomScrollView where it should start from. You pass that to both the `CustomScrollView` and the `SliverAppBar`.

The `SliverFillRemaining` will fill what's left of the viewport, which if you're starting at the `SliverAppBar` will be about 80%. FillRemaining will take you into the box model (as opposed to the Sliver model) which allows you to just use the space as you regularly would with columns and what not.

[image]
[image]